# Remove Double Quotes on Single JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, highcharts, double-quotes

I'm working with HighCharts and having a little trouble getting the color variable to work so it alternates colors.

Here is my returned JSON array:

```
[{"y":5,"color":"colors[0]","drilldown":{"name":"June","categories":["Fictional Hospice","Virtue Hospice"],"data":[4,1],"color":"colors[3]"}}
```

I need to remove the double quotes just from the `colors[0]` and the `colors[3]` part in order for it to work.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Set your cursor behind the `"` you want to remove and hit `<- backspace` key on your keyboard.

Comment: If you remove the quotes, it will no longer be valid JSON.

Comment: Why do you want to remove that? You showing correct `json` format. If you need any data's from there, use [json_decode()](http://us.php.net//manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method

Comment: Because `"colors[0]"` is not a string. It is telling `"colors:"` which one to use. Expected format is `"colors": colors[0]` for Highcharts.

Comment: I think @user2436953 wants to use references of the `colors` array inside his JSON but that's not possible. I would rather just use 0 and 3, and then, after decoding, use `colors[myJSON[0].color]` to get the right value out of the `color` property

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use references of the colors array inside JSON, that's not possible.

I would rather just use 0 and 3 in the `color` property, and then, after decoding, use `colors[myJSON.color]` to get the right value out of the `color` property.

So, your JSON will look like this:

`{"y":5,"color": 0,"drilldown":{"name":"June","categories":["Fictional Hospice","Virtue Hospice"],"data":[4,1],"color": 3}}`

And when you want to get the right color, just use `colors[jsonObject.color]` instead of just `jsonObject.color` if you decoded your JSON string into `jsonObject`